# How to include a code block containing XML in org mode exports?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have some XML inside an org mode file, and when export it to HTML, it's urgent display, so I an thinking of code block, such as

```
#+BEGIN_SRC java

#+END_SRC
```

But there is no XML support. What's the normal way to include XML in org mode?

Comment: What sort of "support" do you need? Do you simply want to include the XML block in your exported HTML?

Comment: yes,include it in exported html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wonder if you've gotten confused by [this list of supported languages](https://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages), which does not include XML.

This list is the languages supported by *Babel*, which lets code snippets be executed from Org. Since XML is a markup language and not a programming language, it is not surprising that it is not included.

As far as I know, source code blocks can be in any language that you wish. The following works just fine for me:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC nxml
<test>
</test>
#+END_SRC
```

When point is in this block, [`C-c '`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-Source-Code.html#Editing-Source-Code) opens up the code block in a dedicated `nxml-mode` buffer, where the content can be edited at will. `C-c '` closes this temporary buffer and updates my Org file.

Exported HTML includes this code block.